# Epics/stories in GitLab FOSS

Tags: gitlab

We have a self-hosted GitLab FOSS instance. This version does not include any epics/stories and there is build-in way to create hierarchy between issues.

We are migrating a project from JIRA. The team that worked on this project where using epics/stories and sub-tasks. Are there any strategies to handle epics/stories in GitLab FOSS. I mean I know we would have to use labels and/or milestores, but has anyone ran into this situation.

Also, I know GitLab Ultimate has epics, but it is too expensive.

Answer (score 1):

Epic in GitLab are indeed part of the ["Portfolio Management" feature (issue 3254)](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/issues/3254#note_42956460) of the GitLab Ultimate edition.

[image: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/uploads/00cd5485dc8df5f869b2a59244d5069d/Screen_Shot_2017-10-10_at_16.05.34.png]

The only free alternative would be to have "sub-issues", which are being discussed in [issue 4588](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-com/www-gitlab-com/issues/4588), and illustrate how you would need to use labels.

For instance:

> All sub-issues must use the same prefix for their title, preferably a meaningful shortened version of the main issue's title if it's too long.
> This is a visual helper to quickly identify sub-issues and their main issue.
>
> **Each sub-issue must have proper labels**:

- the `~sub-issue` label
- the same [type label](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/doc/development/contributing/issue_workflow.md#type-labels) as the main issue
- the same [release scoping label](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/doc/development/contributing/issue_workflow.md#release-scoping-labels) as the main issue
- the same [priority label](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/doc/development/contributing/issue_workflow.md#priority-labels) and [severity label](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/doc/development/contributing/issue_workflow.md#severity-labels) as the main issue
- the relevant [specialization label](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/doc/development/contributing/issue_workflow.md#specialization-labels) to that particular sub-issue

This is still being implemented, with topics like ["Provide first class support for Issue Task Lists and Tasks" (issue 2036)](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/issues/2036).

---

Update March 2022 for GitLab 14.9 (Ultimate edition only)

> ### [Link an epic to another epic](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2022/03/22/gitlab-14-9-released/#link-an-epic-to-another-epic)
>
> GitLab now supports linking epics using “related”, “blocking,” or “blocked” relationships.
>
> This feature enables teams to better track and manage epic dependencies across GitLab groups.
>
> Effective dependency management is a key component of reducing variability and increasing predictability in value delivery.
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/14_9/related_epics_add.png]

---

[GitLab 16.5](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2023/10/22/gitlab-16-5-released/#find-epics-with-advanced-search) (October 2023) adds (for premium/ultimate only):

> ### Find epics with advanced search
>
> The popularity of epics in GitLab continues to grow.
>
> Previously, finding epics was a little more difficult than other content types.
>
> With this release, you can now search and view results for epics when you use advanced search.
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/16_5/epics_are_findable_in_advanced_search.jpg -- Find epics with advanced search]
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/search/#global-search-scopes) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/250699).